# directional lightning

Tags: opengl, game-design, shaders, fragment-shader

I have managed to get a point light working, but I am facing problem with directional lightning.

```
    Fragment shader
 uniform vec4 lightColour ;
 uniform vec3 lightPos ;
 uniform float lightRadius ;

in Vertex {
vec3 colour ;
vec2 texCoord ;
vec3 normal ;
vec3 tangent ; 
vec3 binormal ;
vec3 worldPos ;
} IN ;

  void main ( void ) {
  vec4 diffuse = texture ( diffuseTex , IN . texCoord );
  mat3 TBN = mat3 ( IN . tangent , IN . binormal , IN . normal );
  vec3 normal = normalize ( TBN * ( texture ( bumpTex , IN . texCoord ). rgb * 2.0 - 1.0));
  vec3 incident = normalize ( lightPos - IN . worldPos );
  float lambert = max (0.0 , dot ( incident , normal )); 
  float dist = length ( lightPos - IN . worldPos );
  float atten = 1.0 - clamp ( dist / lightRadius , 0.0 , 1.0);
  vec3 viewDir = normalize ( cameraPos - IN . worldPos )
  vec3 halfDir = normalize ( incident + viewDir );

  vec3 viewDir = normalize ( cameraPos - IN . worldPos );
  vec3 halfDir = normalize ( incident + viewDir );
  float rFactor = max (0.0 , dot ( halfDir , normal )); 
  float sFactor = pow ( rFactor , 33.0 );
  vec3 colour = ( diffuse . rgb * lightColour . rgb );
  colour += ( lightColour . rgb * sFactor ) * 0.33;
  gl_FragColor = vec4 ( colour * atten * lambert , diffuse . a );
  gl_FragColor . rgb += ( diffuse . rgb * lightColour . rgb ) * 0.1;
```

As far as I know, directional lightning do not have a radius or a position, just direction.
How should I calculate directional lightning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the vector direction, you don't need this line

```
 vec3 incident = normalize ( lightPos - IN . worldPos );
```

Instead just pass the direction(incident) vector as a uniform variable, because direction light doesn't have a position (actually it's supposed to be positioned at infinity), so you pass it as a uniform so it's doesn't change with respect to the object.

```
uniform vec3 lightDir;
```

You also don't need the attenuation, because directional light are supposed to simulate lights at "infinity" like sun.

Comment: I have done it, and I removed the radius from float atten. is it correct  , and i kept vec3 incident = lightDir

Comment: Yes what you did is correct, you only pass a light direction and that's all.

Comment: it appears when the radius is set in atten, but directional lights do not have a radius

Comment: yes, they don't have attenuation, so they don't have radius.

Comment: i should have normalize my light direction. i was getting a very bright screen without it being normalized

Answer (score 0):

A directional light is even easier than a point light - the direction of the light is what you use as the `incident` vector, and the rest is the same.

Comment: so what should I change in the incident? I mean assume lightPos is the direction of the light , it should minus by what?

Comment: `incident = lightPos`, then. You compute `incident` which is the vector from the light to the point - the direction from which the light hits the point in the surface. By definition, every ray of a directional light has the same direction (hence the name), so the incident vector at any point in the surface *is* the light's direction.

Answer (score 0):

Think directional lighting as like it's a point light but it just has the same direction for all the fragments. Then just leave out the radius and attenuation, and you got directional light.

Some good tutorials of directional lights can be found [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/directional-light-per-pixel/), [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/directional-lights-i/) and [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-8-basic-shading/).